# web api call from code behind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i am very new to mvc web api

I have crated a web api Post method which takes an object type "Bag" and return a HTMLString the code is as shown bellow

```
public HtmlString PostBag(Bag bagofItem)
    {
       return  Utility.PostBagDiscountedItem(bagofItem);
    }
```

now from my web site i wanted to call the API method PostBag from the controller PostBag()

and i am do not know how to and appreciate if some one can show me how to do this

what i have got in my web application is as bellow.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private Bag _bag = new Bag();
    private string uri = "http://localhost:54460/";

 public ActionResult PostBag()
    {
          // would some one show me how to POST the _bag to API Method PostBag()

        return View();
    }

public class Bag 
{
    private static  List<Product> _bag { get; set; }

    public List<Product> GetBag ()
    {
        if (_bag == null)
            _bag = new List<Product>();
       return _bag;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{

   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54460/");

   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_bag);

   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Success");
   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Error with feed");
   }
}
```